# how to check if visitor liked my facebook fanpage. private website not facebook iframe tabs

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page

Is it possible to check if the visitor of my private Website liked my Facebook Fanpage?
I found many posts for Facebook Iframe-Tabs but not for private Website owner.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a user likes my Facebook Page or URL using Facebook's API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/how-to-check-if-a-user-likes-my-facebook-page-or-url-using-facebooks-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have  the user_likes permission, so you can query the likes the user already has.

And then using the javascript sdk you can achieve it by doing this:

```
function isPageLiked(YOUR_VALID_TOKEN) {
    token = YOUR_VALID_TOKEN;
    FB.api('/me/likes/YOUR_PAGE_ID', function(response) {
        if(response.data.length){
            //the user likes your page do something here
        }
    }, {access_token: token});

}
```